# Fetching dynamic values in wiremock from request json to response json

Tags: json, wiremock, wiremock-standalone

Request Body Payload-

```js
{    
    "request":{
        "method" : "POST",
        "urlPattern" :"/payments/v1/payments",
        "headers":{
            "x-session-id":{
                "matches":"[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\\-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}"
        },       
            "x-request-id":{
                "matches":"[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\\-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}"
        },
            "x-api-key":{
                "matches":"(?s).*"
            },         
           "Content-Type":{
                "equalTo":"application/json"
            },        
           "Accept":{
                "equalTo":"application/json"
            },
            "x-application-id":{
                "matches":"(?s).*"
            },
            "X-Client-Channel":{
                "equalTo":"client"
            },
            "Authorization":{
                "matches":"Bearer [a-zA-Z0-9&._-]{1,}"
            },
            "context":{
                "equalTo":"Pankin ostopolku"
            }   
        },
            "bodyPatterns": [
    
    {"matchesJsonPath": "$[?(@.isRetry == false)]"},  
    {"matchesJsonPath": "$[?(@.debtorAccount.IBAN == null)]"},
    {"matchesJsonPath": "$[?(@.debtorAccount.NotApplicable == 'NOT_APPLICABLE')]"},

    {"matchesJsonPath": "$[?(@.creditorAccount.IBAN =~ /.*/)]"},
    {"matchesJsonPath": "$[?(@.creditorAccount.NotApplicable == null)]"},

    {"matchesJsonPath": "$[?(@.creditorTransactionCode == '500')]"}, 
    
    {"matchesJsonPath": "$[?(@.instructedAmount.amount =~ /.*/)]"},
    {"matchesJsonPath": "$[?(@.instructedAmount.currency == 'EUR')]"},

    {"matchesJsonPath": "$[?(@.intermediaryAccount == '3531800')]"},
    {"matchesJsonPath": "$[?(@.ownMessage == null)]"},
    {"matchesJsonPath": "$[?(@.archiveId =~ /.*/)]"},
    {"matchesJsonPath": "$[?(@.paymentType =~ /.*/)]"}
    
    ]

     }   
  }
```

which looks like

```js
{
    "isRetry": false,
    "debtorAccount": {
        "IBAN": null,
        "NotApplicable": "NOT_APPLICABLE"
    },
    "creditorAccount": {
        "IBAN": "FI2052091920276802",
        "NotApplicable": null
    },
    "creditorTransactionCode": "500",
    "instructedAmount": {
        **"amount": "57000.00",**
        "currency": "EUR"
    },
    "intermediaryAccount": "3531800",
    "ownMessage": null,
    **"archiveId": "202311235SCL00000026",**
    "paymentType": "CREDIT_ONLY"
}
```

Response body payload -

```js
{
        "debtorAccount": {
            "NotApplicable": null
        },
        "additionalId": "0",
        "creditorAgent": {},
        "orderReceipt": "false",
        "needsSplit": "false",
        "transactionCode": null,
        "transactionDate": "2023-11-06",
        "ownMessage": null,
        **"archiveId": "202311065OCL00000007",**
        "transactionId": "59986920448925_2023-11-06_202311065OCL00000007_0",
        "paymentType": "CREDIT_ONLY",
        "paymentId": "A_59986920448925_2023-11-06_202311065OCL00000007_0",
        "creditorAccount": {
            "IBAN": null
        },
        "instructedAmount": {
            **"amount": "11015.42",**
            "currency": "EUR"
        },
        "bookingDate": "2023-11-06",
        "status": "PROCESSED",
        "modifications": {}
}
```

Here I wanted to have the value of archiveId and amount from the request body payload as the value of archiveId and amount in response body payload.

In the JSON how it can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`jsonPath` helper](https://wiremock.org/docs/response-templating/#jsonpath-helper) to extract the values [from the request model](https://wiremock.org/docs/response-templating/#the-request-model).

Given the request body you posted, they would be something like:

```json
{
  ...,
  "archiveId": "{{ jsonPath request.body '$.archiveId' }}",
  "instructedAmount": {
    "amount": "{{ jsonPath request.body '$.instructedAmount.amount' }}",
    ...,
  },
  ...,
}
```

I'm unsure of how you're supplying the response, but you'll need to enable [response templating in the response.](https://wiremock.org/docs/response-templating/#applying-templating-in-local-mode)

```json
...,
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "bodyFileName": "foo.json", // just an example, but you can use `body` or `jsonBody` as well
    "transformers": ["response-template"]
  }
}
```